why my vscode project pops up error message suddenly?
I am making a project using vscode, and using react and springboot.
This error message suddenly pops up, and bothers me.

Could not open cp_init generic class cache for initialization script 'C:\Users\djwls\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\5cb870b7bccc637bbe1a3f9df7c0c634\Oracle.oracle-java\userdir\var\cache\gradle\nb-tooling.gradle' (C:\Users\djwls.gradle\caches\8.6\scripts\4jbi8vk6y16d54n1snyxw6doj). BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'BuildScript' Unsupported class file major version 66

I think this may be caused by gradle, but I don't know the exact reason.
build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    // Java 버전을 명시적으로 설정
    java {
        sourceCompatibility = '17'
    }
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
   implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

I've tried many things but I didn't get any clues.

Do you understand what "Unsupported class file major version 66" means?

Change Project Java Version and
Clean Gradle Cache
